# Cannot redeclare block-scoped Worker thread with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, multithreading, process, configuration

I'm trying to do worker thread in typescript and to be honest I have an error that I cannot solve.

I'm in an app that is fully compiling and working the part is divised in shared function and services(class) each of them are working and used in the app but it's seem there is an error in the worker thread.

this is my error:
`Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'lodash_1'.\n"`

this is how I started the worker in my main.ts

```
 worker = new Worker(path.resolve(__dirname, './workerStart.js'), {
            workerData: {
              path: './worker.ts',
              ...dataNeeded
            }
          });
```

this is the workerStart.js

```
/* eslint-disable semi */
const path = require('path');
const { workerData } = require('worker_threads');
require('ts-node').register();
require(path.resolve(__dirname, workerData.path));
```

and this is the worker.ts

```
import { CONFIG_SERVICE_FROM_FILE_KEY } from '@server/common/config/CommonConfiguration';
import { loadConfiguration } from '@server/common/config/loadConfiguration';
import { initializeAllDaos } from '@server/common/dao/initializeDao';
import { parentPort, workerData } from 'worker_threads';
import { ProfilerService } from '../../profiler.service';

runThread();

async function runThread() {
  const {
    serverConfig
  } = workerData;

  await initDao(serverConfig);
}

async function initDao(config) {
  // it fail on the call of that function
  const daoList = await initializeAllDaos(config.dao);
  console.log(config); // throw before
  return daoList;
```

I followed this link to do worker thread on typescript:

https://wanago.io/2019/05/06/node-js-typescript-12-worker-threads/

This is my tsconfig:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "paths": {
      "@environment": ["./environment.ts"],
      "@server/*": ["./server/*"],
      "@swaggerAPIConfig": ["./swaggerConfig.json"],
      "@dao-core-db/*": ["./structures/dao/db/*"],
      "@dao-db-models/*": ["./structures/dao/db/models/*"],
      "@dao-db-models-sets/*": ["./structures/dao/db/models-sets/*"],
      "@dao-db-models-doc/*": ["./server/api/types/*"],
      "@docs-tools/*": ["./docs/tools/*"],
      "@tests/*": ["tests/*"]
    }
```

In the end I think it's a problem that the worker doesn't use my tsconfig But how can I give it to him ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: From that link -> `The Node.js and JavaScript are often perceived as a single-threaded but in this series, we prove that it is not entirely true.`   No Javascript is still single threaded.  But if you do want to work with workers, I would suggest using https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-worker  as you can then share more code between browser and node..

Comment: okey but does it work with typescript ? And why what I have is not right ? 
Here you are simply telling me to change tool but I don't understand why

Comment: Yes, looking at the repository it has the `.d.ts` file, so yes it will work with Typescript.  It's just advice to change, that link is from 2019 so it pretty out-dated.  But you can continue with it, but with the OP wrongly claiming JS is not single threaded is a bit worrying.

Comment: @Keith JS isn't single-threaded and it has never been. A *language* is not "threaded". The user-provided code *usually* runs in a single thread in JS. But that doesn't mean there aren't threads. Browsers have been running JS in separate threads for decades. Just hasn't always been exposed to page code. All JS on the page was loaded and ran on the same UI thread. Node.js itself uses multiple threads as well, through libuv. It does offload IO and other tasks to it. Web Workers are a way to opt into concurrent execution.

Comment: @VLAZ  JS as in the language JS is single threaded, and always has been.  I never said JS can't use threads, eg. the Browser & Node itself use plenty of threads.  But JS talks to these threads using some form of IPC.  Worker threads in JS are just another instance of the JS engine, if JS was multi-threaded then this of course wound't be the case.

Comment: @Keith [agents](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-agents) are in the spec specifically to allow for multithreading. It also has [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) what is it being shared with if there is only one thread? And if worker threads were really only running on the same thread as everything else as you claim, then they would be entirely useless. Nobody would be using them for crunching harder computation (which is one of their main applications) as that would be blocking all other execution.

Comment: @VLAZ  `worker threads were really only running on the same thread `  I never said that..   And of course there not useless, ..  And I wouldn't say that either.   If you wanted to do some heavy compute, there certainly usefull.

Comment: @Keith You did say there was no multithreading. That implies that worker threads are not multithreading. If they are, then JS is multithreaded and your insistence it is makes no real sense.

Comment: @VLAS   I will repeat, Javascript..  Not the browser or node.   This can spawn as many threads as it likes, and then give the Javascript instance(s), IPC methods to communicate.  Your SharedArrayBuffer link even shows this IPC part via PostMessage, but each JS runtime is still running in a single thread.

Comment: I think in nodejs it's more like process, it re-start a new instance of node to run a program so it's not really a thread but more likely another app that communicate with the first one

Comment: @Saren  Yeah, I'd say that's pretty much the best way to describe it.  I'd also say it's not a bad thing either, not sure if VLAZ was thinking I was down playing JS, after having done threading in other languages, not having to worry about Critical sections / mutex's / deadlocks etc is very refreshing.  Also worth noting even if using say C / Rust compiled to WASM, it's threading is kind of emulated using WebWorkers, SharedArrayBuffer & atomics.